# BASH: how to store subshell variables into an array?

Tags: arrays, bash, function, subshell

I have `array1`, `array2` and a function.

I am trying in a `for j=0 to ARRAY_SIZE` loop to get the data from `array2[j]`, pass it to a function and the returning output store it in `array1[j]`.

Below is the part of the code that I am working on:

```
exec 3>&1
${ppart_block_fstype[$i]}=_ppart_block_fstype < <(
    for i in $(eval echo {0..$ARRAY_END})
    do
        if [[ ppart_block_alloc[$i] -eq "ALLOC" ]]
        then
            printf "%s\n" "${ppart_block_num[$i]}" >&3
        fi
    done)
exec 3>&-
```

`_ppart_block_fstype` is the function that I have previously defined and will return an output that I will store in array `ppart_block_fstype`.
The problem of above function is that is using some "heavy tools", hence is not really possible to invoke it at every loop cycle.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15153158/how-to-redirect-an-output-file-descriptor-of-a-subshell-to-an-input-file-descrip)! was a good starting point, but I am stuck on how to make `$i` visible out of the subshell, and I am also not sure if I am invoking `< <( )*` in the correct way.

Comment: Are you trying to store a corresponding entry in `ppart_block_fstype` for each entry in `part_block_num`? One problem is that your for loop may produce fewer than `ARRAY_END` lines of text. Another is its not clear what `_ppart_block_fstype` is producing for output; presumably, it write multiple lines of output, one per line of input, but you'd have to assign each line to an element of `ppart_block_fstype` separately.

Comment: Btw, you'd be better off using `seq 0 $ARRAY_END`, or even `for (i = 0; i < $ARRAY_END; ++i)`, then doing `$(eval echo {0..$ARRAY_END})`.

Comment: I believe (maybe mistakenly) that `ksh` is a little more lenient with its scoping of variables, but as you say 'how to make `$i` visible out of the subshell ...' I don't really think that is possible. Just to be clear, you want the value for $i from inside the `for` loop from the `process substition` to be used as the value of `$i` in the array index?

Comment: @chepner I am aware that the loop may produce fewer than `ARRAY_END` entries, that is OK, my `ppart_block_fstype` is pre-initialized. `_ppart_block_fstype` accepts one argument as input and produce one line of output through `printf`, this output has to be stored in `ppart_block_fstype`

Comment: @shellter _you want the value for $i from inside the for loop from the process substition to be used as the value of $i in the array index?_ Correct